# Apply Function to Groups of Dask DataFrame

Tags: python, csv, dask

I have a huge CSV-File which I initially converted into a Parquet-File. This File contains Information from different sensors.

```
|    |   Unnamed: 0 |   sensor_id | timestamp           |    P1 |   P2 |
|---:|-------------:|------------:|:--------------------|------:|-----:|
|  0 |            0 |        4224 | 2020-05-01T00:00:00 |  0.5  | 0.5  |
|  1 |            1 |        3016 | 2020-05-01T00:00:00 |  0.77 | 0.7  |
|  2 |            2 |       29570 | 2020-05-01T00:00:00 |  0.82 | 0.52 |
```

In order to process the data I want to create several smaller (using resampling etc.) DataFrames containing the timeseries of each sensor. These timeseries should then be inserted into a HDF5-File.

Is there any faster other possibility besides looping over every group:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np

def parse(d):
    # ... parsing
    return d

# load data
data = dd.read_parquet(fp)
sensor_ids = np.unique(test['sensor_id'].values).compute() # get array of all ids/groups
groups = test.groupby('sensor_id')

res = []
for idx in sensor_ids:
    d = parse(groups.get_group(idx).compute())
    res.append(d)

# ... loop over res ... store ...
```

I was thinking about using `data.groupby('sensor_id').apply(....)` but this results in a single DataFrame. While the solution above calls the `compute()`-method in every iteration leading to a too high computation time. The data contains a total of approx. `200_000_000` rows. There is a total of approx `11_000` sensors/groups.

Can I implemented writing the timeseries to a HDF5-File for every sensor into a function and call `apply`?

The desired result for one group/sensor looks like this:

```
parse(data.groupby('sensor_id').get_group(4224).compute()).to_markdown()

| timestamp           |   sensor_id |      P1 |      P2 |
|:--------------------|------------:|--------:|--------:|
| 2020-05-01 00:00:00 |        4224 | 2.75623 | 1.08645 |
| 2020-05-02 00:00:00 |        4224 | 5.69782 | 3.21847 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here looping is not the best way if you are happy to save the small datasets as parquet you could just use the option `partition_on`.

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
data = dd.read_parquet(fp)
data.to_parquet("data_partitioned", partition_on="sensor_id")
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped a lot. I used `joblib` and `pandas` afterwards to parse every DataFrame (`pd.read_parquet`). Then put timeseries via loop into HDF5-Store.